# Visual proof that neural network can approximate any function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I want to create a neural network that will exactly fit to my sample, however at some point the learning process stops. Different optimizers like adam or sgd also don't work.

[Cybenko](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.441.7873&rep=rep1&type=pdf) proved that the statement from the title is true for any sigmoidal function as an activation function so I want to use either sigmoid or tanh. I want also to keep only one hidden layer.

What are tweaks that I can use? Here is my setup (python3) and results:

```
features = np.linspace(-0.5,.5,2000).reshape(2000,1)
target = np.sin(12*features)

hn = 100 
nn = models.Sequential()

#Only one hidden layer
nn.add(layers.Dense(units=hn, activation='sigmoid', 
                              input_shape=(features.shape[1],)))
nn.add(layers.Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))

# Compile neural network
nn.compile(loss='mse', 
           optimizer='RMSprop', 
           metrics=['mse']) 

nn.fit(features, 
       target, 
       epochs=200, 
       verbose=2, 
       batch_size=5)
```

[image: dark blue - target, blue - prediction]

Comment: try adding more layers

Comment: @user2717954 OP specified he just wants to use one layer.

Comment: Theory says that if your input is over {0, 1}^d and it is a binary classification problem then you need a hidden layer with 2^d neurons. Here you'll need much more. Good luck with that

Comment: @user2717954 theory? what do you mean?

Comment: The (little bit we have) formal theory behind  DNN

Comment: I have experimented a bit, it seems like the straight line solution is a local minimum which is hard to avoid. Using a network with a negative l1 regularization, a higher density of points around the maxima/minima of the function, and a batch size of 1 over 100 epochs i could get out of said local minima, but it would have required more training to get to a reasonably accurate solution (I'm training on a cpu for the moment, so it takes forever to run online training).